# java abstract class for inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a project where I am currently loading the records from the excel file to the database using from org.apache.poi

I have 3 kinds of files that I am loading into different Dto classes.
Two of these dtos shares the same base class (they have common attributes)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PpyRecordDTO {

private String units;
private Double quantity;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class FirstRecordDTO extends RecordDTO {
private String normDescription;
private String relatedUnits;

}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class SecondRecordDTO extends RecordDTO{

private String normName;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class ThirdRecordDTO {

private String code;
}
```

The ThirdRecordDto class has a unique attribute and no shared attributes with the base dto class RecordDTO

I want to return from this method the base class : RecordDto (But ThirdRecordDTO cannot extend it since there are no common fields)

```
    public static List<?extends RecordDTO> readPpyExcelFile(MultipartFile file, SourceType sourceType){
    //TODO: making readPpyExcelFile generic
    try {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream()));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();

        List<? extends RecordDTO> lstRecords = processRecords(rows, sourceType);

        // Close WorkBook
        workbook.close();

        return lstRecords;
    } catch(ApiGenericException apiException){
        throw new ApiGenericException(apiException.getStatus(), apiException.getMessage(), apiException.getErrorType());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new ApiGenericException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"Enable while loading the file", ApiErrorType.Unhandled
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the dto ThirdRecordDto also be returned or inherit from an abstract class which is shared by the other dtos in order to return the type <? extends List from this method?

Comment: You might consider using a "empty" `interface` to define conformance

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer for your response, do you have any examples or links?

Comment: You could make all the classes to implement an empty interface and use that as the generic class instead of the record class. I'm not a big of this since  there is nothing shared that would make sense using an interface. I believe something is wrong when you try to have a superclass with children that share nothing

Comment: Look at [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) - it defines conformance, but no actual functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can go with something like this:

```
public interface Ppy {
 // common methods if any
}

public class PpyRecordDTO implements Ppy{...}
public class FirstRecordDTO extends PpyRecordDTO {...} // so that it also implements Ppy interface
public class SecondRecordDTO extends PpyRecordDTO {...} // the same as above
public class ThirdRecordDTO implements Ppy {...} // Note, it doesn't extend PpyRecordDTO but implements the interface
```

Now in the method, it's possible to:

```
 public static List<Ppy> readPpyExcelFile(MultipartFile file, SourceType sourceType){...}
```

This will work, however, you should ask yourself the following: what will do the code that will call this method, namely how it will differentiate between the different implementations?
If the interface has a common method that makes sense for all implementations - fine, it will be able to call the method. For example, if it has a method like `render(Page)` or something, the code might be:

```
List<Ppy> ppis = readPpyExcelFile(...);
Page page = ...
for(Ppy ppi : ppis) {
    ppi.render(page);
}
```

However, if the interface doesn't have any common methods - it won't help much. Inheritance is used when the child object can be viewed as a specialization of Parent (so that the child "is a" parent). So think whether inheritance is really appropriate here, assuming `ThirdRecordDTO` doesn't have anything in common with the rest of the classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Yes I will think about it.
This method that I am using has common shared code with other files